# Missing Event Viewer descriptions

Tags: windows, service, registry, event-log

I am creating an new installation package for one of our products and I'm having significant trouble getting the event message description DLL to be used by Windows to provide event descriptions to the Event Viewer. I always get the following message in the Event properties:

> The description for Event ID ( 39 ) in Source ( MyProduct) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry
>   information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote
>   computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this
>   description; see Help and Support for details. The following
>   information is part of the event: MyProduct, , , , , , , , ,
>   MyProduct.

My previous installer seems to work fine on other systems. The target operating systems here are WinXP SP3 and Server 2008 R2 and I see the same issue on both. The event message file is registered under the Eventlog\Application key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services with the EventMessageFile and TypesSupported present set to the correct values.

I have tried the following in an attempt to resolve the issue:

- Moving the event message DLL to the System32 folder
- making sure the Event Log service has full access to the event message DLL (2008 only - WinXP is not on a domain so does not have the Security tab in file properties.

Any ideas as I'm running out of options and can't find anything online other than to setup the registry, which I have done from the start.

Comment: Did you also add your source to the Sources value under the Application key?

Comment: Well, you can use Process Monitor to see if Event Viewer is even trying to load your DLL.  If it's not then it's a problem with the registry; otherwise it's a problem with the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out there was a compilation error in our Event Message DLL(!)